# Bootstrap-sass and Bootstrap.css browser compatibility

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, bootstrap-sass

As a learning exercise, I have taken out the Nuget Bootstrap, jQuery, other default packages that are included by default when a new ASP.NET MVC 4.5 application is created with Visual Studio 2013.  Instead, I am using Gulp to supply those packages. (Why? Because I have heard it will be future practice, and so I am getting a head start while I have the time and luxury to learn it.)

My gulpfile requires `gulp-sass`, and while the Bootstrap scss source files are successfully compiled and placed correctly in the specified folder, I find that there is one remaining issue that I have not been able to solve.

When I open the Bootstrap.css folder in Visual Studio, I see the content I would expect to see, but I also see warnings over much of the content, such as "Browser compatibility: add missing standard property", "... is not a valid vendor specific property", and so on. This screenshot is a subsample of the warnings I found in the file.

[image: Bootstrap.css with warnings]

I have looked at various blogs, SO answers, and the gulp-sass pages and have worked out this gulp.task.  While running `gulp` in PowerShell completes successfully without errors, I am wondering if I am missing any packages or if I am missing something in the task that would correctly add the missing vendor tags and browser compatibility tags.

Here are the relevant excerpts from my gulpfile, inspired by the available examples existing online.  It's a large file, so I'm not including the other portions of the code that correctly do what they are written do to.

How can I improve the `gulp.task` so that it produces the correct Bootstrap.css files?

```
'use strict';

// Require declarations

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var bower = require('gulp-bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var del = require('del');
var cleancss = require('gulp-clean-css');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var maps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss'); // just added    

// Read bootstrap scss source files from bower_components
var bootstrapStyleSrc = 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/**/*.scss';
var cssDist = 'Content/Dist/App'

gulp.task('bootstrap-css', ['clean-styles', 'bower-restore'], function () {
    return gulp.src(bootstrapStyleSrc)
        .pipe(maps.init())
        .pipe(sass())                                   
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] })]))
        .pipe(maps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDist));
});
```

Comment: Is this just an IDE warning with VS or are you having problems with older browsers? Also, I'm pretty sure you don't need `postcss` with `gulp-autoprefixer`

Comment: It's an ide warning. However, I do notice that IE doesn't render the css correctly, while chrome, firefox, and edge render correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'm using for [autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer) to target different IE versions. Also check out [gulp-load-plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-load-plugins) so you don't need to create objects for all your node modules.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
       $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('css', function () {
return gulp.src('./assets/css')
    .pipe($.sass())
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'firefox >= 4', 'safari 7', 'safari 8', 'IE 8', 'IE 9', 'IE 10', 'IE 11'],
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe($.cleanCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
```

});

Comment: Is the "$" symbol used in the jQuery sense or in another sense? I have not seen the "$" symbol used in the examples I have seen so far. I also notice that you're running sass at the very last. Don't you need to process the sass before the auto-prefixer and css clean?

Comment: At the top I set $ to the result of calling 'gulp-load-plugins' module. Check out the link to that module. As for the task, yes it's in the wrong order. Sorry I was just showing that as an example of what my autoprefixer task looks like. I'll edit it